# IBM Urabancode using Restful API

Tags: rest, urbancode

Is it possible to pull components, Snapshots and Environment from Dashboard of UrbanCode into my Web application dropdown list using Rest APi. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Pls Go through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the contents of the Dashboard view, which shows currently running processes, you can use the (internal, unsupported) REST API. By opening up the developer tools in your browser or a plugin such as Firebug and then loading the dashboard page, you can see the REST requests that create the page. The request that gets the current activity is something like this:

https://ucd.example.com:8443/rest/workflow/currentActivity?rowsPerPage=10000&pageNumber=1&orderField=startDate&sortType=desc

So you can use that GET call to rest/workflow/currentActivity to get the same sort of info that's on the dashboard. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Thank u Tim for ur response. Another question, I am pulling snapshot and components from urbancode using httprequest. I have been using my own credential, but now how can i use my service account to authenticate. I don't have admin previleages. Is it possible to bypass credential if it is admin.let me know..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "service account." You just need a user account in the system with permissions to access the data. Accessing data via REST API requires the same permissions as through the UI.